# Maximum Speed for Space Travels

Tags: speed, rocket-science, propulsion, warp-drives

Considering a hypothetical spaceship that has an unlimited amount of fuel, traveling within the solar system planetary plane, what would be considered a safe maximum speed for traveling around considering a constant acceleration for a long period of time?

Taking into consideration collision with particles that may produce drag and heat on the hull surface and possible collision with small debris.

Another problem I would like to check here if it is at least plausible, after the ship reaching this -maximum limit- would be possible to just turn the ship around and start accelerating backward to kill some velocity? I mean, to the crew perspective nothing would change, correct?

Comment: Hi, to be clear, you're not talking about speed limits from the Special Theory of Relativity, you're just asking if there are *other* physical reasons that limit the speed of a moving vehicle in space?

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry, I let that unclear, I'm considering a physical speed limit like I said, collision with particles, small bodies, enough time correct course in case of an accident and things like that.

Comment: A few things: 1) The collision rate with small bodies depends _very_ heavily on where exactly you're traveling. For example, being in the same plane as the planetary disk of a solar system makes collisions more likely than being outside of that disk. 2) The collision rate with molecules is anisotropic, so the drag from this is direction-dependent - the solar wind is always blowing from the star, and for things like red giants this can be quite significant; in addition, the composition and density of the interstellar medium depends heavily on where you are in the galaxy. (cont.)

Comment: 3) Accelerating at $0.5g$ isn't going to get you anywhere particularly fast. It'd take almost two days of in-game time to get from Earth to Mars at closest approach, and it'd take more than two weeks of in-game time to get from Earth to Pluto at closest approach, even if you're continuously accelerating (in the Earth-to-Pluto case, your final speed would be 2% the speed of light when you reached it).

Comment: About the speed, I'm considering long term space missions, for instance, a trip that would take a year in constant 0.5G acceleration, by the end of the year the ship would be at 100,000,000 m/s.

About the collision rate, just for me to get an idea, what would be a safe speed to travel on the planetary plane of our solar system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceleration can be achieved by changing the magnitude of the velocity *or* the direction of the velocity. Here is an example-based description/solution:

If you have ever been on a fast-moving merry-go-round, you have probably felt the *centripetal acceleration* pulling you radially outward form the center.

[image: Image from youtube.com]

So, for when the ship is traveling from point A to point B, in addition to its constant speed toward point B, you can have it revolving about an axis at a constant rate such that the "bottom" of the ship is always on the outside of the circle that the ship traces out.

[image: from my OneNote notebook]

For this situation, the *centripetal acceleration* is constant.

For situations where the ship must do non-trivial maneuvering, things get more complicated. Find someone with enough tech experience to be able to simulate the following in a physics engine:

[image: The kinematic equation for rigid body motion. From Goldstein,Poole & Safko chapter 4.10 "The Coriolis Effect"]

Comment: In other words, don't try to use linear acceleration to simulate gravity, and build a rotating station instead so you don't have to worry about "speed limits". But this is assuming that you're only concerned about simulating gravity and not actually getting places within a solar system.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of rotating stations, I'm planning to use that on large space bases, but considering a small ship, this principle is impracticable, isn't it?

Comment: Any magnitude of centripetal acceleration (which would be felt as a force pointing straight away from the origin of revolution) can be achieved as long as the ship can revolve fast enough and close enough to the axis of revolution (at this point, I should give the equation for the magnitude: F=v^2/r). It is somewhat impractical since the ship would use a lot of fuel to maintain this centripetal acceleration, but any "gravity-making" mechanism would require fuel usage.